# How can I change the Owncloud calendar reminder behaviour for shared calendars?

Tags: calendar, reminders, owncloud

I have an [Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/) (Version 8.1.1) running on a little Lubuntu Banana Pi with the calendar plug-in (Version 0.7.3) and 3 shared calenders and desired reminders:

1. Persons A calendar with read-only access for person B. Desired: Just person A gets reminded.
2. Persons B calendar with read-only access for person A. Desired: Just person B gets reminded.
3. Joint calendar for person A and B for common events. Desired: Both gets reminded.

At the moment, only the 3rd calendar works correct. For the 1st and 2nd one both persons get reminded as well, if an event was created with reminder option. How can I change this behaviour, so that only the persons with write access to a calendar get reminded?

Comment: AFAIK unfortunately the Owncloud calendar app 0.7.3 does not support this at all. How did you make it producing reminders?